# Variable life with JavaScript function closures for events

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

If I assign an anonymous function to an element's event in a function then the event will have access to the "environment" of the function, even after the function is done.

What happens if I change the element's event function? Does that previous "environment" get garbage collected or is it still in memory?

Or what happens if I remove the element from the DOM?

```
function blah(div)
{
    var a = 1;
    div.onclick = function(){ alert(a); }; // this alerts 1 as expected because a is in the "environment" of the onclick function
}

blah(someElement);

// somewhere else
someElement.onclick = function()
{
    // i know a is inaccessible here but what happened to it? is it still in memory somewhere?
}

// and what about here?
someElement.parentNode.removeChild(someElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:**
>
> You will want to avoid attaching js objects to a dom node. It
>   will use more memory and will have to be removed individually. A much
>   better way would be to create a js object and then reference the dom
>   node. As always remember to clean up the js objects/events first
>   before removing the dom nodes. Javascript's Garbage Collector is able
>   to detect circular references and handle them correctly, but the DOM's
>   Garbage Collector can not.

This post describes that case: https://www.interworks.com/blog/mgardner/2009/08/31/avoiding-memory-leaks-and-javascript-best-practices

> Referencing a variable outside the scope of a DOM element's event
>   function (formally known as a closure see
>   http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html for more
>   information). The problem is that the variable and function become
>   intertwined due to the reference and will not be collected unless both
>   are freed (won't happen until page unload for global variable
>   references). If the event is never removed/released the garbage
>   collector will never collect both the object and the DOM fully.

**Will Leak Example:**

```
var bigString = new Array(1000).join(new Array(2000).join("XXXXX")); 
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.onclick = function() {
   this.innerHTML = bigString.length;
};
document.body.appendChild(d);
d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
```

**Will Not Leak Example:**

```
var bigString = new Array(1000).join(new Array(2000).join("XXXXX")); 
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.onclick = function() {
  this.innerHTML = bigString.length;
};
document.body.appendChild(d);
bigString = null;
d.onclick = null;
d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
```

Comment: what about attaching events to elements that are already in the DOM like in my example?

Comment: It doesn't matter I think. There is no difference in this case what goes first: binding to an event or adding element to DOM.